# Regex with tag works, but not with specific id?

Tags: php, regex

The following regex:

```
(?!<script[^>]*>)[(.*?)](?![^<]*<\/script>)
```

Targets every [TEXT] and [INPUT] there is in the input string, except any [] within a script tag.

I would now like to change this, to have the exception to be on a specific script with `id="special"` instead.

So `<script id="special">[INPUT]</script>` should not be targeted while another script tag without the id special, like `<script>[INPUT]</script>` should together with the rest of the string.

I tried adding `id="special"` to the above regex before `[^>]*>`, but doesn't work.

Comment: Why the -1 anyone? I would like to improve, but I have to know why?

Comment: @chris85 Thanks for your comment. The format is consistent, but it should "skip" match with all script tags that has id="special". Tried your regex, works, although it doesn't match a new line with [INPUT] only (not wrapped in <script></script>

Comment: So <script id="special"></script> should kind of be a exception to the regex matching. Everything inside this script should not be matched. I start to think i explain pretty bad. Hope you understand.

Comment: Ah that is great! Works! Could this be improved/cleaned up? Not experienced with regex, but seems overdo with a boolean? Also, could you submit this as an answer. Would be great to also add to your comment regarding the HTML being unreliable - why (maybe example? read more?)

Comment: Do you mean you want to first test if the string has `[]` in it before performing the regex? I've posted an answer for the initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip everything inside a `script` element with that id by using the PCRE verbs `skip` and `fail`.

```
<script id="special">.*?<\/script>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\[[^\]]+?\]
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/PSMV15/5/

You can read more about this here, http://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html#skipfail.

If a string is HTML a parser should be used because there can be all sorts of variations in the elements and attributes.

For example:

```
<script  id="special">
<script src="page" id="special">
<script src="page" id="special" class="why?">
<script id='special'>
<script id=special>
<script id=special src=page>
```

without even entering the layered elements issue. Here's one thread on why regexs and HTML shouldn't go together. [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Thank you for this! Great! Lastly, the $1 is empty how can I solve this? I tried modifying the regex to: <script id="special">.*?<\/script>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\[([^\]]+?)\] - wrapping with brackets (), but does not work.

Comment: There is no capture group so it is `$0`. The example you linked has capture group 1.. Where's the decimal entity and is that optional?

Comment: My bad, got it working! In the original script, I was modifying the id="special" to also accept special2, but forgot ?: to only group and not capture.

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean but sounds like it is working for you.. so hooray

Answer (score 0):

You might be going to complex on this.

If you don't want to match a `<script>` element that has any attributes you could use \s for whitespace:

`<\s*script\s*>\[(.*?)\]</\s*script\s*>`

If the only attribute you need to omit is 'id' you could use a 
negative lookahead/lookbehind:

`<script(?!.*\sid=).*>\[(.*?)\]</script>`

That will match `<script` NOT FOLLOWED by `<whitespace>id=` before the `>` character.
For More Help Visit this [Link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. It doesn't match anything with your second solution that are what I would like to accomplish: http://regexr.com/3g7qk